# Using Python 3 to consolidated information from various excel files (same format) into a specific output format

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to consolidate various excel files with 7 worksheets (in the same format) into two consolidated files (specific output format). Am using Pandas.

The code runs well but the consolidated data doesn't write into my output files and the output files remain blank. Would anyone have an idea on what's missing?

Thanks in advance.

The current code is written as follows:

**Current Code:**

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import os
from os import listdir  

fLocation = "Input Files"
dirs = os.listdir( fLocation )

# to run through all 7 files in input file location
for file in dirs:  
    if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
        # Added this to show what file you were actually trying to load. 
        print(file)
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook( fLocation+"/"+file )
        dirSheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Director')
        mdSheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('MD')

        mdW = openpyxl.load_workbook('Outputs Files/Peer Allocation Report MD.xlsx')
        dirW = openpyxl.load_workbook('Outputs Files/Peer Allocation Report Dir.xlsx')

        rowNum = 8
        columnNum = 6

        outRowNum = 7
        outColumnNum = 2
        sheetNum = 1

        totalDirPoolValue = 0
        totalMDPoolValue = 0

        for columnNum in range (6, 13):  # to run through all 7 pool in each input file

            sheetName = "Pool " + str(sheetNum)
            dirPoolSheet = dirW.get_sheet_by_name(sheetName)
            mdPoolSheet = mdW.get_sheet_by_name(sheetName)

            while rowNum < 108:  # to run through all the row in 1 pool in each input file
                dirV = dirSheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = columnNum).value
                mdV = mdSheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = columnNum).value

                dirPoolSheet.cell(row = outRowNum, column = outColumnNum).value = dirV
                mdPoolSheet.cell(row = outRowNum, column = outColumnNum).value = mdV

                rowNum = rowNum + 1
                outRowNum = outRowNum + 1

                # Added this to debug what the issue was. 
                print("{} {} {} {}".format(totalDirPoolValue, dirV, totalMDPoolValue, mdV))
                if mdV != None:
                  totalDirPoolValue = totalDirPoolValue + dirV
                  totalMDPoolValue = totalMDPoolValue + mdV

                # end of while loop

            # to sum all rows to summary row
    dirPoolSheet.cell(row= 3, column = outColumnNum).value = totalDirPoolValue
            mdPoolSheet.cell(row= 3, column = outColumnNum).value = totalmdPoolValue

            sheetNum = sheetNum + 1
            # end of second for loop

        outColumnNum = outColumnNum + 1
        # end of first for loop

wb = Workbook()
wb.save('Outputs Files/Peer Allocation Report MD.xlsx')
wb.save('Outputs Files/Peer Allocation Report Dir.xlsx')
```

Comment: This code is nowhere close to "pythonic and makes no use of pandas.. While You import pandas it never gets referenced in the code there is no need for openpyxl (I don't even know what it is Look here at the pandas doc and do a bit more Google research. Pandas will do all the readand write and file combining you need with no loops.http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html

Answer (score 0):

What if you initialize `totalDirPoolValue` and  `totalmdPoolValue` outside of the loop? Try debugging right before the save commands.

Also, I couldn't tell if anything is stored in wb before saving. It seems like you might be resetting that but I don't know what `Workbook()` does.

You may be interested in looking at the [`pandas.DataFrame.to_excel()` function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) ... and `pandas.read_excel()`